# enlargethispage only if ... (opposite of needspc)

Tags: page-breaking

perts---is there a facility to \enlargethispage only if there is less than x vertical space still available?  this would be an analog to \needspace, but with the opposite effect---not pushing something onto the next page, but trying to squeeze it into the current page before breaking.

regards, /iaw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is already `\enlargethispage*`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

A line

A line

A line

\enlargethispage*{1000pt}
\vbox to \dimexpr\textheight{\leaders\vrule width 2pt\vfill}
\clearpage

A line

A line

\end{document}
```

[image]